# Array.Find on powershell array

Tags: powershell

How can I use the [Array.Find](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d9hy2xwa%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method in powershell?

For example:

```
$a = 1,2,3,4,5
[Array]::Find($a, { args[0] -eq 3 })
```

gives

```
Cannot find an overload for "Find" and the argument count: "2".
At line:3 char:1
+ [Array]::Find($a, { $args[0] -eq 3 })
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodCountCouldNotFindBest
```

The array class has the methods I expect, as given by:

```
PS> [Array] | Get-Member -Static

   TypeName: System.Array

Name            MemberType Definition                                                                                       
----            ---------- ----------
Find            Method     static T Find[T](T[] array, System.Predicate[T] match)
```

Should the array be casted to something else to match the T[] type? I know there are other ways to achieve the find functionality, but I was wondering why this doesn't work.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to cast the `ScriptBlock` as a `Predicate[T]`. Consider the following example:

```
[Array]::Find(@(1,2,3), [Predicate[int]]{ $args[0] -eq 1 })
# Result: 1
```

The reason that you received the error, is because there was no matching method overload, in the case where you're passing in a PowerShell `ScriptBlock`. As you noted in your `Get-Member` output, there is no `Find()` method overload that accepts a `ScriptBlock` as its second parameter.

```
[Array]::Find(@(1,2,3), { $args[0] -eq 1 })
```

> Cannot find an overload for "Find" and the argument count: "2".
>   At line:1 char:17
>   + [Array]::Find(@(1,2,3), { $_ -eq 1 })
>   +                 ~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodCountCouldNotFindBest

Comment: The answer from @Neolisk is the more powershell-y way to do this.

Answer (score 35):

There is no need to use Array.Find, a regular `where` clause would work fine:

```
$a = @(1,2,3,4,5)
$a | where { $_ -eq 3 }
```

Or this (as suggested by @mjolinor):

```
$a -eq 3
```

Or this (returns `$true` or `$false`):

```
$a -contains 3
```

`Where` clause supports any type of objects, not just basic types, like this:

```
$a | where { $_.SomeProperty -eq 3 }
```

Comment: Because -eq also works as an array operator, it's even easier than that: $a -eq 3

Comment: There was a need for Array.Find, because the comparison needed to be done on an object instead of a primitive. The example was over-simplified.

Comment: Neolisk's approach is the powershell way of doing that, even with objects. Ex. `$a | where { $_.MyProperty -eq "Foo" }`.

Comment: @NoMoreMrCodeGuy: It does not matter, the above approach would work with any object. Use `$_.Property` to get a property value on the object.

Comment: Is there a way to get the array index of a search using where rather than the object?

Comment: @uSlackr: Pls ask a separate question, definitely needs more context.

Comment: @Neolisk Yeah - I know better.  Sorry

Answer (score 3):

Another option would be using an [`ArrayList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which provides a `Contains` method:

```
PS C:\> [Collections.ArrayList]$a = 'a', 'b', 'c'
PS C:\> $a.Contains('b')
True
PS C:\> $a.Contains('d')
False
```

Or, as @Neolisk mentioned in the comments, you could use PowerShell's `-contains` operator:

```
PS C:\> $a = 'a', 'b', 'c'
PS C:\> $a -contains 'b'
True
PS C:\> $a -contains 'd'
False
```

Comment: Powershell also has a `Contains` method, like this `$a -contains 3`.

Answer (score 1):

Trevor Sullivan's answer is the right one, not only for Find() static method, but for FindIndex() as well.

When you've got several NIC cards with both ipv4 & ipv6 active on your servers and want to check the ipv4 IP/netmask pairs, something like this is good :

```
$NetworkAdapters = Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -Filter 'IPEnabled = True' | Select-Object -Property Description, IPAddress, IPSubnet, DefaultIPGateway, DNSServerSearchOrder, DNSDomain
$NetworkAdapters | % {
  "Adapter {0} :" -f $_.Description
  # array'ing to avoid failure against single homed netcards
  $idx = [System.Array]::FindIndex(@($_.IPAddress), [Predicate[string]]{ $args[0] -match "\d+.\d+.\d+.\d+" })
  "  IP {0} has netmask {1}" -f @($_.IPAddress[$idx]), @($_.IPSubnet)[$idx]
}
```

My point is it works like a charm on 2012 WinPE, and fails on a production Win7 wks. Anyone got an idea ?

Answer (score 1):

This was run across ~6 million items in a system.array using both methods

```
$s=get-date
$([array]::FindALL($OPTArray,[Predicate[string]]{ $args[0] -match '^004400702(_\d{5})?' })).count
$(New-TimeSpan -Start $s -End $(get-date)).TotalSeconds

20 items
33.2223219 seconds

$s=get-date
$($OPTArray | where { $_ -match '^004400702(_\d{5})?'}).count 
$(New-TimeSpan -Start $s -End $(get-date)).TotalSeconds

20 items
102.1832173 seconds
```