# [System.Array]::Find Method is not supported in powershell

Tags: .net, powershell, lambda

I am using Powershell 5 and try to call some .net class method within powershell. I am following the example here : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d9hy2xwa(v=vs.110).aspx

Then I wrote some code in Powershell:

```
$arr = @()
$arr += 10
$arr += 5
$arr += 7
[System.Array]::find($arr, x => x -eq 10)
```

But I got error:

```
> At line:1 char:21
> + [array]::find( $arr, x => x -eq 5 )
> +                     ~ Missing expression after ','. At line:1 char:22
> + [array]::find( $arr, x => x -eq 5 )
> +                      ~ Unexpected token 'x' in expression or statement. At line:1 char:35
> + [array]::find( $arr, x => x -eq 5 )
> +                                   ~ Unexpected token ')' in expression or statement.
>     + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingExpressionAfterToken
```

Comment: `[Array]::Find((1..10), [Predicate[Object]]{$args[0] -eq 5})`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Array.Find on powershell array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21209946/array-find-on-powershell-array)

Comment: It should be noted that **[Array]::Find is ~50 times slower** than direct comparison `$arr -eq 10 | select -first 1` Of course, you might not notice that after losing time and speed and memory with `+=` on the array (PS creates a new array each time! Use ArrayList or System.Collections.Generic.* types instead)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is your use of "arrow function" syntax.   That syntax isn't supported in PowerShell, though it *might* be possible to substitute a script block, but a few quick experiments didn't find a workable substitute...

The PowerShell comparison operators can operate on arrays, which might be useful in your application.   For your example `$arr -lt 10` returns 5 & 7.   While not quite the same as Array.Find, its sometimes quite useful.

To get the full power of Array.Find, use something like this:

```
$arr -lt 10 | Select-Object -first 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The method is supported - but [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23)-style lambda expressions aren't!

You can substitute the lambda expression with a scriptblock, but you'll have to explicit cast it to a `Predicate` type:

```
$predicate = [Predicate[int]]{param([int]$x) $x -eq 10}
[array]::Find($arr,$predicate)
```

You can also cast it inline:

```
[array]::Find($arr,[Predicate[int]]{param([int]$x) $x -eq 10})
```